# How to fill up space with the new grease pencil tool blender 2.78 (early version)

Tags: grease-pencil

just as the title says how do i fill up the area i want to ?
[image]

because the only way i could get a bigger brush (the only way with grease pencil is by making the pixel bigger (it could only get up to 10 pixel) and it would certainly be a repetitive and not so effective way to do it) sorry if the question is not too clear, i've just get back from work and i'm not at the brightest of time :]

EDIT :

as per suggestion i am editing the question to how can i fill up the space with texture or any other shape that will be able to fill the spaces + on how can i specify where will i fill it up :D

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to show the properties region in the 3DView and expand the Grease Pencil panel to find the colour and opacity settings for the fill.

[image: grease pencil settings]

Comment: thx for the reply, but i want to know how you can fill the shapes, not where the option on how you can fill it (sorry if this sound a bit rude, i'm not at my best today and english is not my first language)

Comment: Increasing the opacity of the fill property is how you fill the shape. GP only offers a solid colour fill, if you want to fill with a texture or other shapes you should add an explanation of what you want the fill to look like to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and suggestion, (i've already edited the question up ), working for 15+ hours sure makes you doozy XD